# A Ring of Square Roots

Tags: ring-theory

$\forall x \exists y(x = y \cdot y)$ is true for the trivial ring and $\mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$. Is it true in any other $\mathbb{Z} /n \mathbb{Z}$ rings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You would need the map $x \mapsto x^2$ to be surjective and hence (since ${\mathbb Z}/{n\mathbb Z}$ is finite) it would have to be a bijection. However $(-1)^2 = 1^2$ and, except in the two cases you mention, $-1 \neq 1$.

Answer (score 4):

no. If any odd prime $p$ divides $n,$ there are quadratic non-residues. If $4$ divides $n,$ there fail to be square roots for any $4k+2,3.$